# How to call js and css files inside a html.erb file

Tags: ruby

I'm quite new to Ruby and ERB and for this case I'm using only Ruby and not rails.

```
E:\ruby
   -app.rb
   -plan.html.erb
   -check.css
   -track.js [js + jquery framework]
```

Inside app.rb I've the following lines

```
text = File.open(("final.html"), "w+")
text.puts ERB.new(File.read("plan.html.erb")).result binding
```

I'm not sure how to call the .js and .css files inside the .html.erb file. Kindly let me know if I've to post the .html.erb file in case that would be helpful to debug further, thanks.

Comment: If you want to _embed_ js/css, you could use the same approach, open the file, read its contents and insert into the html file via ERB's `<%= %>`. But _why_ are you doing this? If you don't like the size/complexity of rails, there are many smaller frameworks.

Comment: I don't understand. If you want to link .js and .css files inside html, don't use just use `<link>` and `<script>` tags?

Comment: @JosephCho: this implies having a server, capable of serving static files. For all we know, this here is a static site generator, not a web app.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : Thank you for your suggestions. I'm very new to Ruby , so still not sure about the supporting frameworks, I come from the system admin side, so these are bit tricky for me. is no other way I can call js and css inside the .html.erb

Comment: @SergioTulentsev Not even, can't you hardcode paths and those files will load when you load html in a browser? Don't need sinatra for that. (btw it is an honor speaking to you)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: SHall I post my .html.erb file ? this is for a small html page generation by reading input file.

Comment: @Rookie1999 "shall I post my .html.erb file" - not yet. Can we assume that you know _precisely_ what html content you want to get? Or, given your background, you have only a vague idea how html/js/css interact?

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : You're right :) I do really have a very little idea how these 3 interacts. I have the idea what HTML content I should have but how to get there is the problem :(

Comment: @JosephCho "when you load html in a browser" - when you load from local filesystem, yes. To put it online, you need a web server.

Comment: @Rookie1999: "I have the idea what HTML content I should have" - I have a feeling that this question will end up closed as "too broad", but let's try it. Post your desired/expected html content, with js/css "called".

Comment: @JosephCho "btw it is an honor speaking to you" - oh stop it, you. :)

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : Thank you sir for your time here.
https://jsfiddle.net/p9mtqhm7/507/ 
I want to expand and collapse table rows when header row is clicked - here say SERVER 1. I only want to expand/collapse rows which are under the specific header (clicked).

Comment: @SergioTulentsev : https://jsfiddle.net/p9mtqhm7/508/ 
I just wanted iterate the final processed data structure and print the respective server and its details as collapsible/expandable format sir. What I have shared is a sample :)

Comment: @Rookie1999: ah yes, embedding. Take a look at frame source of "result" pane. You'll see that your JS is embedded right on the page in a `<script type='text/javascript'>` tag. So that's what you want to do in your template, open JS file, read it, and print its contents with `<%= %>`. See Johan's answer.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev: Thanks much :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can include the JavaScript in the `.html.erb` file in the same way you load the text file. The simplest (code wise) solution is doing something along the lines of this:

*plan.html.erb*

```
<script>
<%= File.read('some/file.js') %>
</script>
```

However if you are expecting a `<script src="some/file.js"></script>` as result you'll have to create your own helper or use an existing one from some light weight web framework. A simple example might be:

*lib/html_helpers.rb*

```
require 'builder'

module HtmlHelpers

  def javascript_include_tag(path)
    Builder::XmlMarkup.new.script('', src: path)
    #=> %{<script src="#{html_escaped_path}"></script>}
  end

end
```

*plan.html.erb*

```
<% require 'html_helpers' %>
<% include HtmlHelpers %>
<%= javascript_include_tag('some/file.js') %>
```

Keep in mind that the first solution doesn't escape any HTML characters. Meaning that if your script contains `</script>` everything following that tag will be interpreted as HTML.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the vivid explanation, that really helped :)